# Fireworks - inner shadow on transparent background

Tags: adobe-fireworks

How to get inner shadow inside rectangle with transparent background?

Comment: Welcome Mat! Have you tried saving as a PNG24 file? Or... provide more details please.

Comment: 1. Draw rectangle
2. make transparent
3 add inner shadow
4. where is the shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the rectangle transparent (the opacity controls everything including any effects applied), just check "**Knock Out**" in the inner shadow settings.